# Nutch and crawling millions of websites

Tags: nutch

Can we use nutch 1.10 in order to crawl millions of websites with several number of round?

I don't really understand the database created when I launch nutch 1.10. Is this enough to crawl the important data from the site?

I have a file with a list of url's that take 2 gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. This is essentially the goal of nutch. However, crawling millions of websites takes time and space, and in order to do, you need to setup the environment correctly.

In nutch 1.X the "crawling database", e.g. which urls visited, what is the urls frontier (next urls to visit),etc. is persisted to the hadoop filesystem. This is the place where you'll first inject your list of urls.

In addition, in order to view to indexed data, you can use solr (or elasticsearch).

I recommend first going through the [nutch 1.x tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) with a **short** list of urls and getting to know how to use nutch and the plugins.

After that, setup an hadoop cluster with tutorials from the [hadoop site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/), and crawl away!